# The use of a superlative in the form "one smart of a cat"

Tags: expressions

I'd like to write in a translation a kind of superlative like
"he was one smart of a cat" to avoid writing "he was one hell of a smart cat".
Is it grammatically correct? Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: "He was one smart cat" would do.

Comment: Thx Mick. I'd like to convey the idea that the cat is smarter than most cats, that he was strikingly smart. Does "He was one smart cat" strike as a kind of 'superlative'? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could say that "He was one very smart cat" (use whatever intensifier you like). The implication in either case is that he was smarter than the average cat.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Sometimes less is more, simpler is more efficient. Thks again.

Comment: But see @user69786's comments.

Comment: He was one smart cat.  OR: He was some cat.  (See EB White's *Charlotte's Web*: "Some pig.")

Comment: Looks like you muddled one idiomatic form with another, as in: “It is a strange idiom, strange enough that I cannot analyze it, but as idioms go it is not *that strange of* an idiom.”

Answer (score 1):

As Mick pointed out, go with *He was one very smart cat*. It uses the following pattern:

> he/she is one something something

Strictly speaking, this is probably not the kind of superlative construction you're looking for, but it will still work for your purposes. An example and explanation follow:

> She's **one beautiful woman**!

What this means is that among all the women of the world there are many beautiful women and she is one of those beautiful women. And I think, *one* there also emphasizes uniqueness in some way. I also would like to point out that *he is one something something* is somewhat similar in meaning to *he is one hell of something something*. So, you can't go wrong with this expression. Use it.

Comment: Thanks. Your example strikes me as the same kind of use of comparative I'd like to use.

Comment: @mrbetyn There is no comparative here at all.

Comment: A comparative might be "he was smarter than the average cat." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Bear#Catchphrases

Comment: Copyright laws prohibit "smarter than the average (animal)".  The Jellystone Park district law society would have field day!

Comment: Literal translations are often not possible. Try employing language localisation if nothing suitable is found